# Why is my ObservableCollection going unobserved?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nlog

I have the following element in a user control, as the sole child of the default `Grid`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogCollection}" Name="LogView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Level}" Header="Level"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedMessage}" Width="500" Header="Message"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Exception}" Header="Exception"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In the code behind, I am handling the following event from a custom NLog `Target`. I am only handling it so because of an example given to me, a total WPF noob, but it seems OK.

```
private void EventReceived(LogEventInfo message)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (LogCollection.Count >= 50)
            {
                LogCollection.RemoveAt(LogCollection.Count - 1);
            }
            LogCollection.Add(message);
        });
}
```

The event fires fine, and the `Add` call is reach when I step through the code. When I mouse-over `LogCollection` in the XAML view at execution time, I see a "Count = 1" after the Add`call, yet my`ListView` remains blissfully unaware it is supposed to be showing me a log event.

OK, OK, the abridged code behind for my user control is:

```
public partial class LoggingControl : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<LogEventInfo> LogCollection { get; set; }
    public LoggingControl()
    {
        LogCollection = new ObservableCollection<LogEventInfo>();
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (Target target in LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets)
        {
            var memoryEventTarget = target as MemoryEventTarget;
            if (memoryEventTarget != null)
            {
                memoryEventTarget.EventReceived += EventReceived;
            }
        }
    }

    private void EventReceived(LogEventInfo message)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        LogCollection.Add(message);
                    }));
    }
}
```

Comment: TwoWay binding does not have anything to do with this scenario.

Comment: @MilanNankov I agree, but still gave it a bash anyway. I am doing nothing in the list that must bind back to the collection, it must only read it.

Comment: BTW, @MilanNankov and my comments are only in the context of another, since deleted, comment that suggested TwoWay.

Comment: The LogCollection is probably a property on a ViewModel? If so make sure that that property raises PropertyChanged when you set it so whenever you re-assign (or initialize) the property a new Observable<LogEventInfo> instance the binding gets updated. To make sure post the code of the ViewModel.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd No, `LogCollection` is a property of the control I declcare the `ListView` on. I know, I should be using a ViewModel, but things must bloody work before they work nicely.

Comment: @ProfK can you anything in `ListView`? For example if you add something to `LogCollection` on click of some temporary button, or even add when list is created, can you see this? Maybe `ItemsSource` binding is broken because context is wrong. Any binding errors in output window?

Comment: If LogCollection is a property on the control, what kind of property is it? It has to be a DependencyProperty to be able to bind to it!

Comment: @ProfK so `LogCollection` is a property of some `UserControl` which also contains your `ListView`? If yes how do you set `DataContext`?

Comment: @dkozl Aaah, maybe you have something. I don't set the `DataContext` anywhere, assuming `Self` would be a default, but I will try that now.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, No, ItemsSource has to be a dependency property, not the source for that property. Otherwise how are all my other user controls binding to view model properties that are POCO properies, not depenency properties?

Comment: @ProfK just remember to do it after you create `LogCollection` because, it seems, it does not raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event

Comment: And we have a winner. @dkozl, please officially answer the question. `DataContext = this` did the trick nicely, thanks. Although it really doesn't make sense that a `UserControl` doesn't assume `DataContext` to be istelf unless told otherwise.

Comment: That is what I told you: you are missing out on the assignment of the LogCollection property because it doesn't raise PropertyChanged. Make it a dependency property or use a viewmodel.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, Or rather just correctly set the data context, then everything works as I planned, without extra dependency properties or a viewmodel. Yes, using a ViewNModel would force me to set the data context, but it would still hide the fact that I was working with an inherited context by default, not Self, as I had assumed. But thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments it seems like binding context for `ListView.ItemsSource` binding is wrong. `DataContext`. In your case setting `DataContext` manually could solve the problem

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

But this needs to be done after `LogCollection` is created as the property itself does not raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.

And to answer why `DataContext` is not set to self by default is because `DataContext` is inherited throughout visual tree. So `UserControl`, as any other `FrameworkElement`, will by default inherit its `DataContext` from the element where it was placed.

Another thing worth noting is that there can be only one `DataContext` value. It will be either inherited from visual tree or set manually in your `UserControl`. You can use inherited context and still bind to `UserControl` properties by using either `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` bindings.

```xml
<UserControl ... x:Name="myUserControl">
    <!--  --->
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogCollection, ElementName=myUserControl}" Name="LogView">
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just realised it makes perfect sense in a `UserControl` that I have to set the dc to Self, otherwise it inherits from its parent. +1 for the extra tip on more explicit binding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that LogCollection that you are actually adding items is the one that you are binding your grid to? I have created a sample application that has your code but works as expected? Maybe you need to post more of your code.

[Here is my sample application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ploicaku01mmyj1/WpfApplication4.zip?dl=0).

Maybe your ItemsSource binding is now working at all. Do you see any binding errors in the console? Something similar to "BindingExpression path error: 'LogCollection' property not found on 'object'"

Comment: Yes, there is only one `LogCollection`. I don't see any errors in the output window, only the log message, because my custom log target also writes everywhere else. I will try adding directly to the collection when I initialize it, to see if it gets the initial contents. Then I will check out your sample, and then some massive edits to post more code without littering up this page too much.

Comment: Probably your binding is not working because your DataContext is not set correctly - your LogCollection is not a propery of your DataContext. You have said that the LogCollection property is defined on the control that you have your GridView. If that is the case simply set the control itself as DataContext in the contructor of the control.

For example, in the contructor of the control -> this.DataContext = this;

Comment: I have said `LogCollection` is a property of my user control, not of anything on my user control or in its `Grid`. I have well said that ListView is the sole child control on my user control.